# Find out which executable references a .NET dll?

Tags: c#

I have a dll file in the workspace of the project which is under maintenance. Is there any method to keep a watch on the dll and see which executable is loading it?

EDIT: I just need to find out which executable loads the dll? Can it be found using Process Explorer. I tried using FileMon by watching the events matching the file name. It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see who is **currently** using or locking a dll.

I'm not aware of any tool that can tell you which executable references your dll *without* the exe actually running. Unless you can know that it is one of a limited number of applications - in which case you could examine each one with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Or you could delete the dll and wait until an executable complains?

This is why the critical (missing) information in your question is whether you are looking to find out who is currently locking your dll, or whether you want to know who will be affected if you change it.

Comment: I'm looking for who is currently locking the dll

Comment: OK, then ProcessExplorer is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to monitor any file access to any file you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe all (.NET) assembly bindings with [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx)

Good [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) about that